# How to apply jQuery methods to a javascript declared variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I declare:

`var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");`

now I want to use this var `iframe` in order to apply jQuery methods:

```
    $("iframe").on("load", function () {
        // DO SOMETHING
    });
```

Like this does not work. How must I reference my `iframe`var

UPDATE: I CAN NOT change the `iframe` declaration method.

Comment: Just take the quotes off.  `$(iframe)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the element in the document before you can select it using `$("iframe")`:

```
$(document).append(iframe);
```

Nevertheless, a handler can be added to an element before you put it in the DOM (which you will have to do sooner or later). You just need to pass the actual DOMElement stored in `iframe` to `$`, instead of a selector string:

```
$(iframe).on("load", function () {
    // DO SOMETHING
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise creating the element with JQuery instead of document.createElement.

The syntax is

```
var iframe = $('<iframe>');
```

Then you can access JQuery functions without wrapping it first

```
iframe.on('load', function() {
    // Do Something
});
```

Comment: And yeah, Asad is right, the main problem you'll have is not having added the iframe to the page :)

Comment: Is there a disadvantage to using `document.createElement` (other than consistency)? I would assume it is faster.

Comment: I'm not sure of the pros and cons for performance, but creating your element with JQuery simply means that you don't later have to wrap it with JQuery